# nativescript-toasty: Expected 1 arguments, but got 3.ts(2554)

Tags: angular, nativescript, toast

I am following a tutorial that in a part of code it uses this fuction:

```
addToFavorites() { 
    if (!this.favorite) { 
        console.log('Adding to Favorites', this.dish.id); 
        this.favorite = this.favoriteservice.addFavorite(this.dish.id); 
        const toast = new Toasty("Added Dish "+ this.dish.id, "short", "bottom"); 
        toast.show(); 
    } 
}
```

But I get this error message because of this line of the code `const toast = new Toasty("Added Dish "+ this.dish.id, "short", "bottom");`
:

> Expected 1 arguments, but got 3.ts(2554)

It seems the `Toasty` class/interface is changed, but I don't know how can I edit my code to get the same functionality?

Comment: Never used it myself but a quick look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-toasty suggests that the constructor is expecting a single opts parameter of type object. e.g. new Toasty({ text: 'Some Message' })

Comment: @RobinWebb: Yes, but the tutorial is from 2017 and maybe the previous version was expecting 3 parameters.

Comment: https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-toasty Looks like the constructor changed on 18/06/2019 "2.0.0. refactor) from onstructor(
    text: string,
    duration?: ToastDuration,
    position?: ToastPosition,
    textColor?: Color | string,
    backgroundColor?: Color | string
  ) to constructor(opts?: ToastyOptions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Toasty is expecting 1 argument, like this:
const toast = new Toasty({ text: 'Toast message' })
You need to use: 
position: ToastPosition
and duration: ToastDuration

Example:

```
const toasty = new Toasty({
  text: 'Somethign something...',
  position: ToastPosition.TOP,
  duration: ToastDuration.SHORT
});
```

Full description:

import { Toasty } from 'nativescript-toasty';
// Toasty accepts an object for customizing its behavior/appearance. The only REQUIRED value is `text` which is the message for the toast.

```
const toast = new Toasty({ text: 'Toast message' });
toast.show();
```

// you can also chain the methods together and there's no need to create a reference to the Toasty instance with this approach

```
new Toasty({ text: 'Some Message' })
  .setToastDuration(ToastDuration.LONG)
  .setToastPosition(ToastPosition.BOTTOM)
  .setTextColor(new Color('white'))
  .setBackgroundColor('#ff9999')
  .show();
```

// or you can set the properties of the Toasty instance

```
const toasty = new Toasty({
  text: 'Somethign something...',
  position: ToastPosition.TOP,
  android: { yAxisOffset: 100 },
  ios: {
    anchorView: someButton.ios, // must be the native iOS view instance (button, page, action bar, tabbar, etc.)
    displayShadow: true,
    shadowColor: '#fff000',
    cornerRadius: 24
  }
});

toasty.duration = ToastDuration.SHORT;
toasty.textColor = '#fff';
toasty.backgroundColor = new Color('purple');
toasty.show();
```

Comment: I changed the line like `            const toast = new Toasty({ text: "Added Dish "+ this.dish.id, short: true, bottom: true})
` but It says `Argument of type '{ text: string; short: boolean; bottom: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ToastyOptions'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'short' does not exist in type 'ToastyOptions'.ts(2345)`

Comment: Thank you but it still says: `Cannot find name 'ToastPosition'.ts(2304)`

Comment: Can I see your code? Did you import it?
import { Toasty } from 'nativescript-toasty'

Comment: Perhaps reading https://semver.org would also benefit your understanding of why the API changed and why the former does not work with the 2x version

Answer (score 3):

The constructor changed on 18/06/2019 in change "2.0.0 refactor" from:

```
constructor(
    text: string,
    duration?: ToastDuration,
    position?: ToastPosition,
    textColor?: Color | string,
    backgroundColor?: Color | string
  )
```

to

```
constructor(opts?: ToastyOptions)
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-toasty/v/2.0.0

Comment: To add to this, if the major changes, according to semver it is a breaking change. Hence the change in the API, which is causing your issue. If you want to avoid breaking changes with javascript projects, make sure to pin your version of a dependency. 

https://semver.org/ - good reading for the OP